# changing extent() to aggregate over a specfic grid of a RasterLayer

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, r-raster

I am currently working with some data from Switzerland with 100x100 m resolution. I would like to aggregate the data to 1x1km from km-squares based on the national grid (with coordinates f.i. x = 500000, y = 130000), differing from the original extent of my RasterLayer object. I have provided some code for a RasterLayer based on the original extent (=r) and a RasterLayer with a new extent based on national grid cells in Switzerland (=r.agg) and plotted r.agg over r (the latter of, which I coloured in red to make the borders more obvious).

```r
library(raster)
ncol <- 3677 # same as original RasterLayer
nrow <- 2261 # same as original RasterLayer

## create raster (with original extent)
  r <- raster(ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow) # dimensions of raster
  mat <- matrix(runif(ncol*nrow, 0,2), ncol = ncol, nrow = nrow) # write data
  # create simplified country-borders / buffer
    mat [0:100, 0:ncol] <- NA
    mat [0:nrow, 0:100] <- NA
    mat [(nrow - 100):nrow, 0:ncol] <- NA
    mat [0:nrow, (ncol -100):ncol] <- NA

  r[] <- mat #write data to raster
  extent(r) <- matrix(c(479950, 73950, 847650, 300050), nrow = 2) # define extent 
  proj4string(r) <- "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556
   +lon_0=7.439583333333333 
   +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 
   +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 
   +units=m +no_defs"

## create raster (with customised extent)
  r.agg <- r # prepare aggregatable RasterLayer
  extent(r.agg) <- matrix(c(480000, 74000, 847700, 300100), nrow = 2)
  r.agg <- aggregate(r.agg, fact = 10, fun = mean)

  par(bg = 'darkgrey')
  plot(r, col = "red", legend = FALSE)
  plot(r.agg, add = TRUE)
```

However, I am not entirely sure to interpret the results correctly:
The plotted "r.agg" over "r" shows a red line which I don't quite understand.

[image: combined plot using example code]

Option A (desired outcome): `extent()` allows me to aggregate over the national grid and aggregate over the spatially correct 100x100m information

Option B (which I hope does not happen): `extent()` will let me aggregate over the national grid, but using the data from the original grid and thus not the one from the correct 100x100 squares.

I didn't find the help page for `extent()` particularly helpful and would be glad to receive some clarification. If Option B is the case (or I misunderstood something completely), I would be really happy if someone could help me to figure this out. Thanks a lot in advance and sorry for my weird phrasing, I am new to analyzing spatial data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two rasters do not align, so you cannot rely on aggregate alone.
You can do

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol = 3677, nrow = 2261, ext=extent(479950, 847650, 73950, 300050))
crs(r) <- "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 
   +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
r.agg <- raster(nrow=227, ncol=368, ext=extent(480000, 848000, 73100, 300100))

x <- resample(r, r.agg)
```

Or, to have more control

```
r.low <- disaggregate(r.agg, 10)
r.low <- resample(r, r.low)
ra <- aggregate(r.low, 10, mean)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Robert, I did not know about `resample()`, that helped a lot!